# Finding the "NOR" of two times

Tags: java

I have a format of two arrays representing the start and end of a time slot, i.e 9am-5pm represented as:

```
int[] startTime = {9, 0};
int[] endTime = {17, 0};
```

The aim is to find, from a list of these (Held in a basic class, format is for ease of database entry), the periods of time in which no element occupies (I guess it could be referred to as NOR?). For example, when provided 09:00-14:00 and 16:00-17:00 (And suppose only entries between 9am-5pm are of interest), it should return 14:00-16:00.

The list is not particularly large, although it will likely contain duplicates and be out of order. I have no idea where to proceed at this point, any ideas?

To clarify: One list of times are being compared to another (Once is local, the other pulled from elsewhere)

Comment: what about 0-9 and 17-24?

Comment: If only discrete hours are permitted, you could use a `BitSet` to flag the occupied hours, then find the unoccupied ones later.

Comment: So you got one general start/endTime, and a list of several start/endTime?

Comment: @Kepotx thats the basic principle, yes. One general list of start/end times, actually. Probably didn't make that clear enough in the post

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Sort intervals by (end time, start time), in ascending order

Step 2: Merge intervals if end_time(i) >= start_time(i+1)

At this point you have a deduplicated, sorted list of non-oberlapping intervals.

Step 3: Output all (end_time(i), start_time(i+1))

Answer (score 0):

Can you read Scala code and translate it to Java yourself?

```
case class Interval (lower: Int, upper: Int) {    
    def deflate () : List [Int] = {(lower to upper).toList}
}

def list2disjunctIntervals (li: List[Interval]) : List[Interval] = {
  val united = (li.flatMap (_.deflate).distinct).sorted

  def split (l: List [Int], sofar: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = l match {
    case Nil => List (sofar)
    case h::t=> if (sofar.isEmpty) split (t, List (h)) else
      if (h == sofar.head + 1) split (t, h :: sofar)
      else sofar :: split (t, List (h))
  }

  val sublists = split (united, Nil)
  sublists.map (l => Interval (l.last, l.head))
}
```

Demo:

```
val li = List (Interval (0, 4), Interval (7, 12), Interval (1, 3), Interval (5, 8), Interval (15, 17), Interval (16, 22))

scala> list2disjunctIntervals (li) 
res64: List[Interval] = List(Interval(0,12), Interval(15,22))
```

In prosa: Interval is a class, defined by its bounds. Deflate is the only method (so far) which produces - for an interval the values in that interval: (9, 12) => (9, 10, 11, 12)

list2disjunctIntervals takes a List of Intervals. It has an inner method united, which deflates all intervals, than reduces the values to distinct ones, and sorts them. So for (3,4)(6,9)(9,11) it produces (3,4,6,7,8,9,10,11).

Split takes this List, and divides it into multiple Lists: (3, 4) and (6,...11).

The last call is to generate new Intervals from the sublists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough Java approach:

```
import java.util.*;

class Interval {

    int lower, upper;

    Interval (int l, int u) {
      lower = l;
      upper = u;
    }

    boolean isMergeable (Interval other) {
        return (upper >= other.lower && lower <= other.upper);
    }
    /**
        if a contains b fully, result is a
        if b contains a fully, result is b
        if a and b don't overlap result is (a, b)
        if a and b overlap, result is Interval min(a.lower, b.lower), max(a.upper, b.upper)
        i(10,12).merge (13, 17) fails
    */
    List <Interval> merge (Interval other) {
      List <Interval> li = new ArrayList <> ();
        if (lower < other.lower && upper > other.upper)
          li.add (this);
        else if (lower > other.lower && upper < other.upper)
          li.add (other);
        else if (upper < other.lower || lower > other.upper)
          {li.add (this); li.add (other);}
        else
          li.add (new Interval (Math.min (lower, other.lower), Math.max (upper, other.upper)));
        return li;
    }   

    // the usual, boring stuff from here    
    @Override
    public String toString ()
    {
          return "[" + lower + ":" + upper + "]";
    }

    // to make List<Interval>.contains(interval) work
    @Override public boolean equals (Object o) {
      if (! (o instanceof Interval))
        return false;
      Interval other = (Interval)o;
      return lower == other.lower && upper == other.upper;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode () {
      return 1023*upper + lower;
    }
}
```

And a Test situation:

```
public class IntervalTest {

  static List <Interval> mergeList (List <Interval> li) {
    List <Interval> iset = new ArrayList <> ();
    for (Interval i1 : li) {
      Interval m = i1;
      for (Interval i2 : li)
        if (i2.isMergeable (m))
            m = i2.merge (m).get(0);
      if (! iset.contains (m))
          iset.add (m);
    }
    return iset;
  }

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    Interval[] ia = {new Interval (0, 4), new Interval (1, 2), new Interval (7, 12), new Interval (1, 3), new Interval (5, 8), new Interval (15, 17), new Interval (16, 19), new Interval (9, 13), new Interval (22, 23)};
    List<Interval> li = Arrays.asList (ia);
    System.out.println (li);
    System.out.println (mergeList (li));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
// atomic Intervals:
[[0:4], [1:2], [7:12], [1:3], [5:8], [15:17], [16:19], [9:13], [22:23]]
// merged:
[[0:4], [5:13], [15:19], [22:23]]
```

Note that the borders - are they included or not? - are differently understood in every day life, so when I say I watch TV from 1-3 and from 4-5, there is obviously a gap between 3 and 4.

But if I say quarter 1 goes from month 1-3 and quarter 2 from month 4 to 6, there is neither a gap between q1 and q2, nor between month 3 and month 4. The given algorithm makes a gap between 4 and 5 so this has to be adjusted if otherwise needed/preferred.

To find open time slots, you have to sort the merged array, and find (if any) time before the first interval, after the last interval and the intervals between.

But if, in your use case, the starting time 0-9 and 17-24 is always included in the List, you only have to search for the intervals between.